# Static equivalent to -forwardingTargetForSelector:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working with a static class that only delegate methods to an instance of another class. It's a kind of wrapper for Core Data context :

```
implementation CoreDataUtil

static NSManagedObjectContext* context; 

+ saveContext {
    [context saveContext];
}

... (several static methods)

@end
```

I'm not very happy with this approach. So I re-designed all differently.

For legacy considerations (old calls to CoreDataUtil class methods), I would like to keep the CoreData class. I would like it to "redirect" undefined methods to another instance.

I know it can be done for instance method with the 'forwardingTargetForSelector'. But I would like the same mecanism for class method (that redirects to instance methods).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem myself and tried a lot of things, including the ones described in my question here: [forwardInvocation to other class instead of instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862984/forwardinvocation-to-other-class-instead-of-instance)

After all, unfortunately it doesn't seem possible to catch method calls on the "static", i. e. class method, level.