# forwardInvocation to other class instead of instance

Tags: objective-c

I have a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) singleton that I'd like to forward some class method calls to some "static" class.

At first glance, `forwardInvocation:` appeared to be a possible solution, however, `NSInvocation`'s `invokeWithTarget:` and `setTarget:` only accept an `id`, i. e. a pointer to an instance, not a class itself.   I tried handing over `[MyTargetClass class]` as the target, but I still get a "No known class method [...]" error when I call `[Facade someForwardedMethod]` somewhere. When I call `[[Facade sharedInstance] someForwardedMethod]` I get a "No visible @interface [...] declares the selector [...]" error.

Of course I am aware that I also need to override `respondsToSelector:` and `methodSignatureForSelector:`, so my code looks like this:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    if ([super respondsToSelector:aSelector]) {
        return YES;
    } else {
        return [MyTargetClass respondsToSelector:aSelector];
    }
}

- (NSMethodSignature *)methodSignatureForSelector:(SEL)selector {
    NSMethodSignature* signature = [super methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    if (!signature) {
        signature = [MyTargetClass methodSignatureForSelector:selector];
    }
    return signature;
}

- (void)forwardInvocation:(NSInvocation *)anInvocation {

    SEL aSelector = [anInvocation selector];

    if ([MyTargetClass respondsToSelector: aSelector]) {
        [anInvocation invokeWithTarget:[MyTargetClass class]];
    } else {
        [super forwardInvocation:anInvocation];
    }
}
```

Is there a way to make this work, or do I have to choose another approach?

---

EDIT: I have tried both ways that Rob Napier mentions in his answer, here are my findings:

I can call a class method in my target class through the facade instance with

```
[(id)[Facade sharedInstance] doSomethingClassyInTargetClass];
```

It's a bit uglier than I hoped for, but it works. However, I can not call a class method in my target class when I address the facade class. To quieten the compiler I can write

```
[(Class)[Facade class] doSomethingClassyInTargetClass];
```

but then it throws an 'NSInvalidArgumentException' "[Facade doSomethingClassyInTargetClass]: unrecognized selector sent to class [...]" at runtime. Apparently the class methods of the facade class get resolved without respect for `forwardInvocation:`, but after all it has a `-` in front...

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you're trying to forward an instance invocation to a class? Is there any reason you don't just make your Facade also a singleton so that you can forward instance invocations to the instance and class invocations to the class?

Comment: Actually that would be the ideal. However, forwarding of class method invocations to that other class would be good enough, if that is possible. Shouldn't that work with the same code anyway? I tried it, and it doesn't work either. I amended the question accordingly... I'd like to avoid instantiating the other class, it's huge and contains nothing that would benefit from it.

Comment: A class object **is** an instance; it's an instance of its meta-class. You may need to use a cast to convince the compiler of that. Also, have you tried the new fast forwarding mechanism `-forwardingTargetForSelector:`?

Comment: Well, of course I am aware that a class object is an instance, but obviously there are differences in quality that the compiler takes offence at... How exactly would you cast? I haven't looked into `-forwardingTargetForSelector:`, but it looks promising, thanks for the hint!

Comment: here is great!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22622747/how-can-i-forward-class-methods-in-objective-c

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ah, when you added the "No visible @interface [...] declares the selector [...]", it is all clear.

Consider a simpler form with just instance methods. You implement `-forwardInvocation:`, and then you have code like this:

```
[obj doSomething];
```

Now, `MyObject` doesn't actually claim `doSomething` in its header, even though it will respond to it. So the compiler complains that this probably won't work. The fix for that is:

```
[(id)obj doSomething];
```

When you declare something `id`, the compiler stops checking whether the target actually implements the selector. But it's also possible that *no* interface declares `doSomething`. Then the compiler is once again suspicious that it's probably a typo, and gives you a warning. And by "no interface," I mean "no interface that the compiler has access to." The compiler only has access to interfaces in this compile unit (i.e. the .m file and the headers it includes). So you need to make sure you include the header that defines this selector.

Now for classes, you can't use `id`, but you should be able to use `Class` to achieve the same thing, such as:

```
[(Class)MyClass doSomethingClassy];
```

If may want to see the [RNObserverManager](https://github.com/rnapier/ios5ptl/blob/master/ch04/ObserverTrampoline/RNObserverManager.h) sample code from iOS:PTL Chapter 4 which demonstrates something similar.

You should also definitely look at `forwardTargetForSelector:` that Ken Thomases references.

---

You don't have to cast `sharedInstance` to `id`. Just change the signature, since you'll always want to use it that way:

```
+ (id)sharedInstance;
```

Comment: I tried it and amended my question with my findings. Not all of it works as I hoped, but I suppose it's good enough for my purposes. Thank you!